# What pattern fits between a façade and a DAO?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I'm in the process of designing part of my companies architecture for its Java EE web applications. I'm pretty clear on the reasons to use a façade and one or more DAOs. The problem I have is this:

There will be some logic that definitely belongs in the integration tier because it's all about keeping the data model consistent. Except the logic goes beyond simply maintaining referential integrity and other 'raw' persistence tasks which will be handled by JPA and Hibernate. I don't class this as business logic because it's separate to any business function. However, my understanding is that a DAO should only implement the logic required to access and persist objects to the data source.

My conclusion is that I need a 'business object'-like pattern which is appropriate for the integration tier. I've looked around and the closest thing I have found (yet still not quite right to my mind) is the [Sun Transfer Object Assembler pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/TransferObjectAssembler.html).

Either there's a gap in my understanding of Java EE or there is a pattern out there that will fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe a [mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) is what you want:

> Define an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact. Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently.

then you can use a `DaoMediator` in order to coordinate two or more `DAO`s

Comment: After reading all the answers my feeling is a mediator is the way to go for us. 

Many thanks for the replies. They have all been very informative.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you may be missing a controller, and consequently may need the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern. The controller will look after the DAOs and present a consistent view (don't think in terms of GUIs, burt rather some client-facing interface). When modifications are made via this view, then the controller coordinates the changes to the model via the DAO. I suspect that your facade objects may be the view in this scenario.

Having said this, I wouldn't worry *too* much about identifying particular patterns. You often find that taking into account all your requirements and separating concerns where applicable, that you end up implementing a particular pattern and only identify it as such after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using aggregates from Domain Driven Design?
I'm a student of DDD myself and it seems the business logic you're trying to design could be accomplished by richer POJO-like domain models. You'd have each 
domain object to be responsible for its aggregate objects, and also including any logic concerning that business concept; that said, your integration layer would coordinate those rich objects but would refrain from having real logic per se (i.e several conditional logic).

Perhaps the pattern you're trying to find is actually a step into richer domain objects?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a DataMapper (or Adapter) pattern between your DAL and your Business Layer, but without a more concrete understanding i couldn't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

What is driving the requirement for consistency between the DAOs?  If there is some business assumption that is dictating the relationship.  For example, you might have an invoice type that when it is 'Capital' then we have to make sure several other objects are in the right state or have the right set of values.  This is definitely outside the realm of the data-layer.

I wouldn't try to hard to find the perfect pattern for this case.  You need some sort of coordinating class though, a mediator or controller of some sort.